# Create a hyperlink to an email address in OpenOffice/LibreOffice Writer

Tags: macos, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer

I am running OpenOffice 3.4 on OS X 10.6.8. How do I link to an email address in a Writer document. I tried typing the email address in the document, selecting it, clicking the link button on the toolbar, filling in the email address where it says "Receiver", and clicking "Apply", but when I do that, nothing happens. The dialog doesn't close, nothing seems to change, and it does not give me any hint why. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

**EDIT:** As ChimneyImp suggested, I upgraded to LibreOffice. I tried the same thing and I am seeing the same behavior.

**EDIT 2:** After some tinkering and experimenting, I think I realized what happened. The "Apply" button is making my changes but it is not closing the dialog box like I thought it was supposed to. Feel free to vote close this question.

Comment: Sorry but I won't. I don't see why I should. It worked even without the `mailto:`. I just didn't realize that it was working.

Answer (score 1):

Prepend the e-mail address with `mailto:` , like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help. I can maybe try it again to make sure I did it right, but I won't get a chance to try it for a few hours.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't help.

Comment: hmm... I just realized I actually used the most recent version of LibreOffice, - I mentally edit OpenOffice into LibreOffice these days.  This sounds like a bug.  This might not be the solution you're looking for, but if you can you should upgrade to LibreOffice <https://www.libreoffice.org/>.  It's a fork of OpenOffice, essentially the same thing but it's being currently updated and OpenOffice isn't.

Comment: I installed LibreOffice and tried the same thing, and I am having the same result.